# Softball foul ball rules

Tags: softball

If a ball is hit fair, but rolls foul before passing third of first then is it foul or fair ?I am asking this because this happened and my P.E. teacher called the ball fair, and I believe that it is foul. Please help resolve this issue.

Comment: Please be precise about the rule set you're using.

Answer (score 1):

If it rolls foul before reaching first or third base, it is foul.  If it is fair at that point, and then rolls out, it is fair.  You are correct.

> Here are 3 of 8 regulations for a foul ball
>
> 1. Settles or is touched (not caught) on or over foul territory between home and first base or between home and third base.
> 2. Bounds or rolls past first or third base on or over foul territory.
> 3. While over foul territory, touches the person, attached or detached equipment, or clothing of a player or an umpire or any object foreign to the natural ground

[ASA Softball: Fair or Foul Ball](https://fastpitchblog.wordpress.com/2012/05/02/asa-softball-fair-or-foul-ball/)

1 and/or 2 apply in your example.  The blogger is directly referencing the rule book with this listing, but the link in the blog is outdated.

Comment: That link is dead. Also, unless it includes an ISF document, then no, it's not the rule book.

Comment: @Nij - thanks for the heads-up, there was a typo in the link. There is no difference between the ISF and ASA rules on foul ball definition, unless you can point to something that says otherwise.  I've looked at the ISF rules, and they are identical to what is listed in my answer.  There is no difference.

Comment: Better to make that clear, and best to use the international rules reference either way.